# Why is it not showing any results in the Table / Collection Section?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, nodejs, express

this is my transport.request.model
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
Transport : String,
Product : String,
Material : String,
Capacity : Number,
Manufacturer : String,
Retailer : String,
currentOwner : String,
Status : String, // setup request // accepted request by distributor //  raw material received by retailer
IsActive : { type : Boolean, default : true},
IsAcceptedbyDistributor : { type : Boolean, default : false},
Isfulfilled : { type : Boolean, default : false},
timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

const model = mongoose.model('transportRequest', schema);

export default model;
and this is the view code. It shows the profile, but does not show the table

```
<div class = "profile-flex">
    <div class="profile">
        <h2><img id ="profimag" src="https://icon-library.com/images/coder-icon/coder-icon-13.jpg" alt=""> Profile</h2>
        <div class="details">
             <ul >
                <% if (Data.Profile != {}){ for (var prop in Data.Profile ) { %>
                    <li> <%= prop %> : <%= Data.Profile[prop] %></li>
                <% } } else {%>
                    <li>No data available</li>
                <% } %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<!-- Table / Collection Section -->
<div>
    <h2>Requests on the Transport Network</h2>
    <div class = "box">
    
         <% if (Data.Requests != []) { for (const Request of Data.Requests) {
            console.log("if first is working") %>
        <div class="card">
            <div class = "container">
                <form action="/distributor/accept-request" method="post">
                    <% if (Request != {}) {  %>
                    <label for="Product"> Product :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Product"  readonly value = <%= Request.Product %> ><br><br>
                    <label for="Material"> Material :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Material" readonly value = <%= Request.Material %> ><br><br>
                    <label for="TransportAddress"> Transport :</label>
                    <input type="text"  name="TransportAddress"readonly value= <%= Request.Transport %> ><br><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Accept Request">
                    <% }%>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% } } %>
```

and finally the route code where I think the problem is , but I'm not sure

router.post('/confirm-fulfillment-of-request', async (req, res) => {

```
// to contract needs to fulfill at the same, html form will have 2 fields : product Address and transport address

// accessing the cookie
const user = req.cookies.accessToken;


await db.transportRequest.findOne({ Transport: req.body.TransportAddress, IsActive: true }).then(async (result) => {

    if (result == null)
        return res.send({ Success: false });
    else {
        // update the Product contract
        const productContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(product_ABI, req.body.ProductAddress);
        await productContract.methods.fulfillRequest(result.Material).send({ from: process.env.defaultAccount });

        // update the Transport Contract
        const transportContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(transport_ABI, result.Transport);
        await transportContract.methods.fulfillRequest(result.Material).send({ from: process.env.defaultAccount });

        // update productrequest collection in database
        await db.productRequest.updateOne({ Product: req.body.ProductAddress }, {
            $set: {
                currentOwner: user.ContractAddress,
                Status: "Raw material received by retailer",
                IsActive: false,
                Isfulfilled: true
            }
        });

        // update transportRequest collection in database
        await db.transportRequest.updateOne({ Transport: req.body.TransportAddress }, {
            $set: {
                currentOwner: user.ContractAddress,
                Status: "Raw material received by retailer",
                IsActive: false,
                Isfulfilled: true
                
            }
        }).then(async(result)=>{
              console.log("result", result)
              // update the retailer stock in rawmaterials
              // update on database
              
              await db.transportRequest.findOne({ Transport: req.body.TransportAddress}).then(async (ress)=>{
                await db.rawMaterial.updateOne({Material: ress.Material, Owner : ress.Manufacturer}, {
                    $set: {
                        Owner: user.ContractAddress
                      }
                  });

                  await db.rawMaterial.findOne({ Material: ress.Material, Owner: user.ContractAddress }).then(async (docs) => {
                    await db.tracking.create({
                        CertificateID : docs.CertificateID,
                        Operation : "Confirm-delivery-of-Goods",
                        From : req.body.TransportAddress,
                        To:  user.ContractAddress,
                    })
          });
       })

              
              
        })

        
        
        // pay the distributor his money from smart contract
        // 
        res.redirect('/retailer-page');
    }
})
```

});